# How can I VPN into a domain and act as if it is local?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, windows-server-2008, remote, domain

I've looked and looked and the internet seems to have finally failed me, there's no information on my specific issue. I have two locations, and one server (sbs 2008); I need them to act like one physical LAN. I know it's possible, I just don't know how to set it up, or anything about VPNs, etc. So, just to clarify a bit more:

- Two buildings, Building Remote and Building Main, 30 miles apart
- For the sake of explanation, let's have the IP addresses be 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8
- 1 Small Business Server 2008 in Building B, now known as "SBS08"
- 15 Computers with varying systems from Windows XP to 7 in Building Remote
- 15 Computers etc. in Building Main
- Computers in Building Main and SBS08 are in the domain, let's name the domain "Paul.local"
- Computers in Building Remote are in a workgroup, let's call "PETER"
- Users need to access shared folders on SBS08
- Users need to be able to get to the exchange server, SBS08
- I do not have a firewall/router capable of being an endpoint for VPN in Building A
- My knowledge of VPNs, Active Directory Sites and Services, And how to set either up is equivalent to a caveman, and not a particularly bright one.

TJ mentioned (down in the answers) having to have two different subnets, sites, a link between the two, and VPN tunneling. I would like to know how to set up two different subnets/sites with the inter-site transport link in AD Sites & Services. If at all possible, I would also like to take the computers in PETER and put them into Paul.local without having to drag them all the way to the other building. I assume I would have to use a VPN tunnel, but I can't just connect the two firewalls, so hopefully I would be able to tunnel from either a client to the firewall in Building Main, or tunnel from the client to the server itself. Either way, I don't know how to set up a VPN at all. So, in it's entirety, I would like to know the following:

1. How to set up AD Sites & Services
2. How to set up a VPN for the two location
3. How to rob PETER to pay Paul.local without going to his house; i.e. To get computers on the domain over VPN
4. How to make and set up better jokes, but that's not as important as the other three.

Thank you TJ for helping me reform my question.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by External network. It sounds as if you have internal networks that you would like to connect over VPN.

Comment: @TJ, there are two physical buildings that are something to the effect of 30 miles apart. Each has an internal network, but what I want is for computers in Building A to connect to the server in Building B and act as if they are on Building B's internal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for Building A and B to be on the same physical network but they can talk across a VPN Pipe. Depending on your firewall and what you use for VPN will dictate how to configure your VPN tunnel. The networks will have to be different subnets so they can route correctly across the VPN and if you have an Active Directory domain you will need to add both IP subnets to the subnet in the AD Sites and services along with your inter-site transport Link. As long as DNS is configured correctly when they search for the server by name they should resolve the name correctly. If they are trying to search through my network places you will need to put in an IP Helper to be able to search. This is because searching across My Network Places will only search across the computers current subnet.

So first you will need to get a device/endpoint that you can use for your VPN tunnel from the Remote building and the VPN created. The creation of this VPN Tunnel will depend on what devices you have on each end. After the VPN has been created make sure all your end points in Peter need to have DNS configured to use your Primary AD server (SBS08) and then you can add them to the domain.

Configuring the AD Sites and Services is simple

1. go to your server or use your remote administrator tools and open Active Directory Sites and Services MMC
2. Expand "Sites" and click on "Subnets"
3. Right click on "Subnets" and select "New Subnet"
4. in the dialog box that comes up fill out the Prefix box using network prefix notation for the network in Paul.local (192.168.0.0/24 would be all IPs between 192.168.0.1 through 192.168.0.254)
5. select the Site object for the Prefix which should be Default-First-Site-Name if you only have one domain and you didn't change the name of the site object.
6. click OK and you have created the subnet
7. repeat steps 3 through 6 for the second subnet in PETER

Now start adding the computers that are in PETER to your domain that is in paul.local and they should then be able to use their login accounts to access resources on SBS08 with no issue.

Comment: Thank you for all of the info, I didn't know I needed to have different sites and a link. My question is more of how do I set that up? I need them to be on the domain through a VPN pipe, etc etc. I don't really have a firewall capable of VPN tunneling in Building A, but I do in Building B. Perhaps I should just revise the question? Thank you for your time, the question should be revised momentarily.

Comment: Edited my answer based on the rework of the question

Comment: Thank you very much sir @TJ. I won't have the ability to follow your directions yet, but it seems fairly straightforward to do. My only last question is, could VPN just go from client to server, with no need for firewalls that can VPN tunnel? For instance like a laptop which is in a public area? Again, thank you for your time!

Comment: Typically a client can connect to a Device that Sets up the VPN tunnel. This device is on the network of the server you want the client to have access to. But not only does the client have access to the server but the rest of the network, as long as the policy on the VPN allows it. Hope that is clear on how VPN works.